# How to open header file (.h) in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm tired of right clicking on the header file in c++ and choosing open document "blahblah.h"
Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have VS 2005 installed anymore, so I can't guarantee it, but in 2008 you don't need a macro or VA-X for this (though you certainly **want** *Visual Assist X* if you don't have it). I don't recall much change in this for quite a while, so I'd expect it to work in VS 2005 as well.

Select `Customize...` from the `Tools` menu. Click on the `Keyboard` button at the bottom left corner of the dialog that comes up. In the "Show Commands Containing" field, type in "header". One of the commands that shows up should be something like "EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.GotoHeaderFile". Select that. In the `Press Shortcut Keys` field, press the keys you want to use to open the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Visual Assist or write a macro.
http://www.alteridem.net/2008/02/26/visual-studio-macro-to-switch-between-cpp-and-h-files/